# php contact form not sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, email

Ive made a Contact form for my Club. [here](http://www.acherner-bogenclub.de/contakt2.php) And now i got stuck with the issue that the form won't deliver the Information from the form which had been inputted to the email address.
I don't know if there is a Problem with the html Code or PHP so ill post both.
HTML:

```html
<form action="#" method="post" style="max-width: 75%;">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Anrede:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="radio" name=Anrede value="Hr.">Herr
        <input type="radio" name=Anrede value="Fr.">Frau</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="140" align="right">*Nachname:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="nachname" value="" style="width:100%;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Vorname:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="vorname" value="" style="width:100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Firma:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="firma" value="" style="width:100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Postanschrift:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="strasse" value="" style="width:100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Telefon:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="telefon" value="" style="width:100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*E-Mail:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" style="width:100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Buchungstag:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Erwachsene:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <select name="Erwachsene" style="width: 145px;">
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Bitte ausw&auml;hlen</option>
          <?php for ($i=0 ; $i <=3 0; $i++) : ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <?php echo $i; ?>
          </option>
          <?php endfor; ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Jugend:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <select name="Jugend" style="width: 145px;">
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Bitte ausw&auml;hlen</option>
          <?php for ($i=0 ; $i <=2 5; $i++) : ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <?php echo $i; ?>
          </option>
          <?php endfor; ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">*Event:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="radio" name=myradio value="extern" checked>extern
        <input type="radio" name=myradio value="intern">intern</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <textarea rows="12" style="width:100%" name="text" placeholder="zus&auml;tzliche Informationen ..."></textarea>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" nowrap>
        <br />
        <input type="reset" value="Formular l&ouml;schen" style="width:49%" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Formular absenden" style="width:49%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p>*Pflichtfelder</p>
<br />
```

PHP:

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$anrede = $_POST['Anrede'];
$last_name = $_POST['Nachname'];//required
$first_name = $_POST['Vorname'];//required
$Firma = $_POST['Firma'];
$Anschrift = $_POST['Postanschrift'];//required
$tel = $_POST['telefon'];//required
$from = $_POST['email'];//required
$tag = $_POST['buchungstag'];//required
$erwach = $_POST['Erwachsene'];//required
$jugend = $_POST['Jugend'];//required
$zusatz = $_POST['text'];

$to= "kontakt@acherner-bogenclub.de , $from";
$subject = "Anfrage auf belegung des Bogenplatzes";

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$from)) {

$error_message .= 'bitte einen gultige email eingelben.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .']+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$F_name)) {

$error_message .= 'Dein vorname ist nicht gültig.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z ']+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Anschrift)) {

$error_message .= 'bitte eine gültige addresse eingeben.<br />';

} 

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$L_name)) {

$error_message .= 'Dein nachname ist nicht gültig<br />';

}


if(isset($_REQUEST['Erwachsene']) && $_REQUEST['Erwachsene'] == '0') { 
echo 'Bitte anzahl der Erwachsene auswählen.<br /> '; 

} 
if(isset($_REQUEST['Jugend']) && $_REQUEST['Jugend'] == '0') { 
echo 'Bitte anzahl der Jugendlichen auswählen.<br /> '; 

} 
  //datepicker validation????

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

die($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Kontaktformular details siehe unten.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}

$email_message .= "Anrede: ".clean_string($anrede)."\n";

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Firma: ".clean_string($Firma)."\n";

$email_message .= "Postanschrift: ".clean_string($Anschrift)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telefonnummer: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Buchungstag: ".clean_string($tag)."\n";

$email_message .= "Anzahl der Erwachsenen: ".clean_string($erwach)."\n";

$email_message .= "Anzahl der Jugendlichen: ".clean_string($jugend)."\n";

$email_message .= "Zusätzliche Informationen: ".clean_string($zusatz)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".

@mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->


Vielen dank. Wir werden sobald wie möglich mit ihnen in verbindung treten. 


<?php

}

?>
```

I hope that somebody could help me with that and also the Validation does not work for some reason and I've tried so many different ways but never worked.

Comment: what's the error that you are getting?

Comment: Remove the `@` in front of your mail command, it suppresses error messages that might be helpful. Check what variables contain. Check if mail sending basically works by using `mail()` directly with strings, no variables.

Comment: Note about your checks: They will fail on names and addresses containing umlauts.

Comment: Is your PHP code in the same file as your HTML / or Using AJAX ? I see that your action attribute is empty, if you have your PHP script in a separate file specify the correct path in action.

Comment: @Vincent the php is in the same file as the html

Comment: @GeraldSchneider could u maybe do an example then for Umlauts pls?

Comment: The `@` before the `mail` will suppress **any error** that may happen during the send process. Moreover, I personally suggest you to use a mailing library like phpmailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer . It will surely solve most of your problems and will tell you exactly what is happening if a mail encountered any issue when sent. That said, please check if all the POST variables are being received. (also, the encoding at the beginning of the php file is a must in my opinion, do not  forget about it)

Comment: Maybe not related to your issue, but also your e-mail validation regex is Just Plain Wrong. The good people at `info@dot.swiss` would not appreciate the assumption that a TLD can only have 4 letters, for example. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: ive delited the @ infront of the mail but i didnt Change anything it only stays at the contakt form with out posting al of the variables :/ @briosheje

Comment: what is `print_r($_POST);` printing? if it's empty, then the if below is not even being joined. (also, keep in mind that the exit is just for debugging purposes, everything **after** the exit won't be executed, the purpose of it, right now, is to check whether any POST data is being received)

Comment: it prints: Array ( [nachname] => sdf [vorname] => [firma] => [strasse] => [telefon] => fdg [email] => [myradio] => extern [text] => [submit] => Formular absenden ) @briosheje

Comment: As for validation, László Müller (his mother is Hungarian ;)) is not going to appreciate you telling him that his name is not g`ü`ltig. (`ü` won't match `[A-Za-z ]`, etc.) And God forbid someone actually types in "Etwasstraße" instead of "Etwasstrasse".

Comment: Well, as long as the "email" field is empty (try to set action="#") it will never ever work, try to submit some data and check if it's all okay. if it is, remove the exit; and see what happens, if the mail is not sent there probably are some issues in the mail send configuration (in the php.ini, usually). That's why I'm personally recommending you to take a look at the library suggested above (phpmailer) in order to configure the SMTP and so on. Also, keep in mind that Piskvor's point is extremely important, validating in the correct way is a must.

Comment: @Piskvor how would u then solve that issue then so that nobody gets excluded :D

Comment: Array ( [Anrede] => Hr. [nachname] => sdfsd [vorname] => dfdsf [firma] => dfd [strasse] => dfdrfgtv [telefon] => dfdf [email] => ******@gmial.com[Erwachsene] => 2 [Jugend] => 1 [myradio] => extern [text] => sdf [submit] => Formular absenden ) @briosheje ive entered some data but it still showed this and ive also did Action="#"

Comment: @Mark: As for e-mail, see the linked question. As for the other fields, just check that they're filled out with *something* - `if(trim($someField) === '') { // empty, show error }`. (Building a list of "these are the only possible characters in a name" is futile and *will* bite you: letters only? Then hope that Mike O'Hare never tries to send a form.) http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: If you're sending to `gmIAL.com`, I have an idea why it's not getting delivered to `gmAIL.com` ;)

Comment: @Piskvor is sending it to kontakt@acherner-bogenclub.de but it doesnt work...

Comment: @Piskvor when i Input ure advice from bevor then mike O'Hare can sent a form? :D

Comment: First off, just because the e-mail leaves your server is *not* a guarantee that it will be delivered. That said, see http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/

Comment: re validation: Try and see. I'm not going to write your code for you, I don't think you could afford that ;)

Comment: @Mark : My final suggestion is to ask you to please rewrite your code using PHPMailer: read about SMTP authentication (and gmail authentication), as Piskvor said: the fact that the mail seems to be sent does NOT guarantee that it will be delivered. Use PHPMailer for such tasks, it's just beatiful, easier to read and works perfectly (and, most important, tells you if something is not working). About filtering: it's FULL of topics in stackoverflow but Piskvor, again, gave you all you need to accomplish everything, just click every link above and you will solve your problems ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `<form action=''` tab is empty, the form is not submitting data when sending and reloading the page. By simply setting `action='#'` I have made your page work in as much as the `print_r($_POST);` now correctly displays the form content.

P.S> [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is absolutely the way to go, regarding PHP emails.

**Further Notes:**

---

```
 if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
   died($error_message);
 }
```

The [Die funtion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) should not be in the past tense.

---

`$email_subject` as seen in the `mail();` function is an undefined variable.

---

```
$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Anzahl der Erwachsenen: ".clean_string($erwach)."\n";
```

These three variables ($first_name,$ast_name,$erwach) are also undefined.

---

*PLEASE* read and check your own code before coming to Stack Overflow. We love to help but we can't be expected to be your typo- and error- checkers.

---

Debug:

```
if (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
    die("Message was sent ok!!");
}
```

---

Your `clean_string` function looks pretty pointless and should be expanded into a full string cleaning function rather than an ad-hoc removal system.

Comment: thanks but how come that this then doesnt sent the emails to the email addres given?

Comment: @Mark I have added some further notes for you.

Comment: thankls for the hint for my spelling mistakes UPS :O now atlest im getting redirectet to the thank you page. but the email still wont come through

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```php
print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

on the line before `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

This will then show you if the form is even posting to the PHP form and also show what it is posting.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You can comment on any post when you reached 50 reputation points, until then please don't post comments as answers.

Comment: http://www.acherner-bogenclub.de/contakt2.php so i just have added ure addvice but i have no clue what this is telling me maybe ull have a look.@user2958426 
@Gerald schneider ive changed what u said but it will not sent the email and only stays at the form even tho when clicked submit :/

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP code above the HTML code if using on the same page.

And PHP code needs few correction as mention below:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$anrede = $_POST['Anrede'];
$L_name = $_POST['Nachname'];//required
$F_name = $_POST['Vorname'];//required
$Firma = $_POST['Firma'];
$Anschrift = $_POST['Postanschrift'];//required
$tel = $_POST['telefon'];//required
$from = $_POST['email'];//required
$tag = $_POST['buchungstag'];//required
$ewach = $_POST['Erwachsene'];//required
$jugend = $_POST['Jugend'];//required
$zusatz = $_POST['text'];

$to= "kontakt@acherner-bogenclub.de , $from";
$subject = "Anfrage auf belegung des Bogenplatzes";

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$from)) {

$error_message .= 'bitte einen gultige email eingelben.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .']+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$F_name)) {

$error_message .= 'Dein vorname ist nicht gültig.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z ']+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Anschrift)) {

$error_message .= 'bitte eine gültige addresse eingeben.<br />';

} 

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$L_name)) {

$error_message .= 'Dein nachname ist nicht gültig<br />';

}


if(isset($_REQUEST['Erwachsene']) && $_REQUEST['Erwachsene'] == '0') { 
echo 'Bitte anzahl der Erwachsene auswählen.<br /> '; 

} 
if(isset($_REQUEST['Jugend']) && $_REQUEST['Jugend'] == '0') { 
echo 'Bitte anzahl der Jugendlichen auswählen.<br /> '; 

} 
  //datepicker validation????

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Kontaktformular details siehe unten.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}

$email_message .= "Anrede: ".clean_string($anrede)."\n";

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Firma: ".clean_string($Firma)."\n";

$email_message .= "Postanschrift: ".clean_string($Anschrift)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telefonnummer: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Buchungstag: ".clean_string($tag)."\n";

$email_message .= "Anzahl der Erwachsenen: ".clean_string($erwach)."\n";

$email_message .= "Anzahl der Jugendlichen: ".clean_string($jugend)."\n";

$email_message .= "Zusätzliche Informationen: ".clean_string($zusatz)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".

@mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->


Vielen dank. Wir werden sobald wie möglich mit ihnen in verbindung treten. 


<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: atlest now it is not staying at the contact form but i still do not recive the email from the form.

Comment: Write `echo` before `$from` and check if you are getting the email address or not

Comment: Also check 'SMTP' setting on your server